# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx dy \exp(-5x^2+8xy-5y^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals, polar-coordinates, jacobian

I need to evaluate the following integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx dy \exp(-5x^2+8xy-5y^2)$$

I know the normal double integrals but this one seem different, moreover, I'm familiar with $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2)dx = \sqrt\pi$$ but I cannot figure out the polar substitution for $-5x^2+8xy-5y^2$ expression. I tried substituting $x^2+y^2$ at $-5(x^2+y^2)$ with $r^2$ and $8xy$ with $r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta$. And then I got even more lost.

Can someone please help me figure this question out and is there any general solution for such problems? And also can someone provide me a link to similar problems and their solutions in order for me to understand better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the substitution $x=\frac{a+b}{\sqrt2}$ and $y=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt2}$, then your integral becomes\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2-9b^2}\,\mathrm db\,\mathrm da&=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2}\mathrm da\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-9b^2}\mathrm db\right)\\&=\sqrt\pi\frac{\sqrt\pi}3\\&=\frac\pi3.\end{align}

Comment: How did we reach to a point where we substituted $x=(a+b)/\sqrt(2)$ and $y=(a-b)/\sqrt(2)$ ? From what intuition?

Comment: No intuition at all here. I just noticed that$$-5x^2+8xy-5y^2=\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-5&4\\4&-5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$and that$$\left\{\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right),\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right\}$$is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-5&4\\4&-5\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. That's why I did tht substitution.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much! Would you mind sharing a few links for practice questions such as these, that would be very helpful for me!

Comment: I am not aware of any site for such a type of exercises. My favourite textbook for this topic is Marsden and Hoffman's *Elementary Classical Analysis*.

Comment: I'm much obliged! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, we complete the square to notice that

$$-5x^{2}+8xy-5y^{2}=-5\left(x-\frac{4}{5}y\right)^{2}-\frac{9}{5}y^{2}$$

so we get that

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-5x^{2}+8xy-5y^{2})dxdy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-5\left(x-\frac{4}{5}y\right)^{2}-\frac{9}{5}y^{2}\right)dxdy.\tag{1}
\end{align*}

For any value of $y$ it holds that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-5\left(x-\frac{4}{5}y\right)^{2}\right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-5x^{2}\right)dx$$

because of the substiuttion $u=x-\frac{4}{5}y$, so substituting back into (1) we get that

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-5x^{2}+8xy-5y^{2})dxdy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-5x^{2}-\frac{9}{5}y^{2}\right)dxdy\\
&=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-5x^{2}\right)dx\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{9}{5}y^{2}\right)dy\right)
\end{align*}

Now making the subs $u=\sqrt{5}x$ and $u=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}y$ we get that

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-5x^{2}+8xy-5y^{2})dxdy\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-x^{2}\right)dx\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-y^{2}\right)dy\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{5\pi}}{3}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{3}
\end{align*}

So we are done